# Hosting Ripple Emulator

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, ripple, taco

I used the files in npm/node_modules/ripple-emulator/pkg/hosted in IIS website to emulate my phone app online, when I open it in browser with ?enableripple=true the ripple starts but it's not loading the app and shows "Looks like what we have here is a failure to... emulate" after loading I tried main root, /assets, /ripple/assets but never got ripple to load my index.html
Does anyone knows how to host ripple in iis?

Comment: Ripple is a local emulator, it can't serve things. If this is your point.